# Multiplicação de vetores A e B resultando em matriz C

Tags: java, array

Estou com um exercício em Java aqui para resolver mas não consegui entender exatamente o que preciso fazer, se alguém puder me dar uma explicação melhor agradeço! Preciso fazer o seguinte:

Dados os vetores `A = [1,2,3,4,5]` e `B = [1,2,3,4,5]`, crie algorítimos para gerar uma matriz C da multiplicação dos elementos de A pelos elementos de B. Observe que

```
C[1,1] <- A[1,1] * B[1,1]
C[1,2] <- A[1,1] * B[1,2]
C[1,3] <- A[1,1] * B[1,3] 
...
```

Comment: Que número seria o B[1,2] ?

Comment: O número 2 no caso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar dois laços intercalados para fazer este tipo de operação: o mais externo preencherá linhas da matriz resultante, enquanto moverá os itens do primeiro array(vetA), o segundo preencherá colunas da matriz resultante, enquanto move itens do segundo array(vetB):

O código fica dessa forma:

```
int[] vetA = {1,2,3,4,5};
int[] vetB = {1,2,3,4,5};
int[][] mat =  new int[5][5];

for(int i = 0; i < vetA.length;i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < vetB.length; j++){
        mat[i][j] = vetA[i] * vetB[j];
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < mat[0].length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < mat.length;j++ ){
        System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Resultado:

> ```
> 1 2 3 4 5 
> 2 4 6 8 10 
> 3 6 9 12 15 
> 4 8 12 16 20 
> 5 10 15 20 25
> ```

Veja funcionando no ideone: https://ideone.com/Qp7iYG

Perceba que, como temos uma multiplicação que resultará em uma [matriz quadrada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_(matem%C3%A1tica)#Matriz_quadrada), pode-se utilizar a mesma combinação para exibir na tela.

Comment: Isso mesmo! Eu estava chegando perto mas faltavam algumas coisas haha obrigado!

Comment: @Leonardo disponha :)

Comment: @Leonardo na próxima mostra o que tu já tem feito, caso o Diego não esteja por perto, fica mais fácil de ajudar :D

Comment: @diegofm Uma duvida na hora de exibir, pq vc usou mat[0].length no primeiro for e mat.length no segundo?

Comment: @Leonardo porque mat[0].length retorna o total  equivalente de "colunas" da matriz, e mat.length retorna o total equivalente as "linhas". Perceba que esse laço funciona corretamente apenas em matrizes quadráticas(totalLinhas = totalColunas)

Comment: Ahh entendi, muito obrigado!